# Play Sound while onDraw

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I would like to play a sound during my game.
But the sound only plays for a half second everytime when I start the app.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Shapes shapes = new Shapes(this);
    setContentView(shapes);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.back);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
      catch (IOException e) {}
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
}
```

mp.setLooping(true) does not help, it only works when I remove "setContentView(shapes);".
What can I do that the sound does not stop after a half second?

Answer (score 0):

If the sound is short, add looping

```
mp.setLooping(true);
```

Also, you mentioned in the title the `onDraw()` method, but the gove you gives is from `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use setLooping(true)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Shapes shapes = new Shapes(this);
        setContentView(shapes);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.back);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
          catch (IOException e) {}
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
```

Comment: When I set looping true the sound also stops after a half second.

Comment: Try use selLooping before mp.start();

Answer (score 0):

Your MediaPlayer object (`mp`) plays one time when `mp.start()`;

If you play continually then, add `setLooping(true)`.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.back);
try {
    mp.prepare();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Fixed your answer so your code looks better.

Comment: When I set looping true the sound also stops after a half second.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a game, i'm assuming it runs in a thread. 
does your game run in a thread?

your thread should have a doStart() or similar method with a MediaPlayer already declared.

a truncated basic example for starting background music in your game thread:

boolean BGMisOn;
MediaPlayer BGM;

doStart()
{
...
...
if(BGMisOn)BGM.start()
...
...
}